# Unable to instantiate driver SQLServerDriver in Wildfly 10

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, wildfly-10

I am having the following error:

```
15:02:34,434 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "sqlserver")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0034: Unable to instantiate driver class \"com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver\". See log (WARN) for more details"
```

The `module.xml` in $JBOSS_HOME\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver" slot="main">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc42.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

This is the content of sqljdbc42.jar

[image: content_of_sqljdbc42]

And the driver definition in `standalone.xml`

```
<driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

Please help me find out what I'm not seeing

**UPDATE:**

> For historic context: the "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver" package is
>   from the old SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver, they changed it somewhere
>   around 2005 to "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc" by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i can see from the jar content the class package in your driver is wrong, try with

```
<driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

Comment: I tried this again, apparently when I refreshed I did not take the changes. Your solution is correct. Thank you

Comment: For historic context: the `"com,microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver"` package is from the old SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver, they changed it somewhere around 2005 to `"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc"`.